# How can I load Flutter WebView on app start?

Tags: flutter, dart

I am developing an app where there is a WebView that will be viewed a lot. The people telling me what to do therefore wants the website to load when the app starts, so that it will be ready when the user decides to open the page with the WebView.

One of my ideas were to use a `Future<http.Response>`, as described [Here](https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/networking/fetch-data), but I don't think that will work since WebView expects a string as initialUrl.

Do you have any ideas on how I can achieve this?

Thanks!

Comment: do you mean something like preloading the view in order to "have it ready" when it needs to be shown?

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I want

Comment: Did you made any progress on this topic?

Comment: The best solution I could come up with was to use a Stack to always have the WebView in the background. But that is not an ideal solution I in my opinion, and we eventually gave up on the idea.

Comment: Can you not show `CircularProgressIndicator()` until it loads. I mean that gives the idea that we are loading, right @HannesHultergård ? You can use the indicator in the `WebView` `placeholder`